# ContentView's content isn't shown if it isn't visible at the beginning?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem to show the content of an overlay when a Task is running. I did a very simple Xamarin.Forms shared project that reproduces the problem (at this moment I'm only running it in an Android emulator). I have 2 main elements in the page: an `StackLayout` with a `Button` (to show the overlay) and a `ContentView` with another `Button` (to hide the overlay):

OverlayPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OverlayTest.Pages.OverlayPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
      <Button x:Name="showOverlayButton" Text="Show overlay" Clicked="ShowOverlayButtonClicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <ContentView x:Name="overlay" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0">
      <Button x:Name="hideOverlayButton" Text="Hide overlay" Clicked="HideOverlayButtonClicked"/>
    </ContentView>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

OverlayPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace OverlayTest.Pages
{
    public partial class OverlayPage : ContentPage
    {
        public OverlayPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowOverlayButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.overlay.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void HideOverlayButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.overlay.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

App.cs:

```
using OverlayTest.Pages;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace OverlayTest
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new OverlayPage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, when I click on `showOverlayButton` the grey layer is shown, but it's content (`hideOverlayButton` button) is not visible. If I change the xaml setting `overlay`'s `IsVisible` property to `True`:

```
<ContentView x:Name="overlay" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
             IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0">
```

and I run the app, then I can see the grey layer with a big `hideOverlayButton` button. In this case I can hide the overlay, and show it again, and hide, show, hide...

It seems that the `ContentView`'s content have to be visible at the beginning... How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Created a Solution and added the Pages exactly as you stated. and It worked fine with no issues. the App started with the Overlay Hidden and when Clicked to Show the content of the Overylay was visible and was able to Show/Hide as expected.

My recommendation for you is to make sure you have the latest version of Xamarin.Forms because there was an addressed issue before, see link 
[Visibility issue with dynamic content of a ContentView](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36002)

The Version I used v2.3.1.114

Let me know your updates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you are were right. I was working with the default Xamarin.Forms library (an older one). Now the overlay's content is visible! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Xamarin.Forms misses re-rendering of the content. In this case you can explicitly trigger the re-render process of the view by calling **ForceLayout()** function on the parent view.
In your case, you'd have to call :

```
overlay.ForceLayout();
```

after changing its visiblity.